# Can we begin a question with "To" or "From"?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, questions

Please consider the following questions.

> From which shed should I take it?
>
> To which house should I send it?
>
> From which printer is it being printed?

Are they correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

They're correct, but they also sound a little stilted. There used to be a [myth](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/grammar-myths-prepositions/) that it's bad to end a sentence with a preposition, and in some languages it really doesn't make sense to end a sentence with a preposition, but it's often pretty natural in English, especially when the sentence is a question.

These sound more natural, at least in contemporary English:

> Which shed should I take it from?
>
> Which house should I send it to?
>
> Which printer is it being printed from?*

---

*To me, a native speaker of American English, "printed from" sounds wrong in this sentence. I'd say "printed on" or even "printed at". But as the commenters have noted, this usage varies.

Comment: IMO, both "from" and "on" are acceptable for a printer. "Which printer is this being printed from?" is pretty natural to me.

Comment: At least as a British English speaker, I don't think I would say that something is being printed "on" a printer, it sounds unusual to me. "Printed from" a printer is what I would probably use.

Comment: "Which printer is printing it?" is maybe better. Avoids the to/from confusion.

Comment: To me, *Which printer is it being printed [preposition]?* is mostly awkward because of the two derivatives of ***print***. So far as the specific preposition is concerned, I'd probably go for *Which unit is it being printed **by**?*, but ***on, at, from*** are certainly all "credible".

Answer (score 0):

In the English question, you have to start either by a **W H pronoun** like who, how, ...etc or by an auxiliary verb. It is unnatural to start a question by a **preposition**.